# Scanning a network and SSH each IP until I get in through SSH

Tags: linux, networking, ssh, ip, nmap

Normally, I would SSH into that machine using:

```
ssh user1@123.45.67.8
```

That server in my network is forced to use DHCP in the subnet (`134.96.90.0`). And everytime it shuts down, I have to go find the possible IP using:

```
nmap -sP 123.45.67.0/24
```

Which outputs:

```
Starting Nmap 6.40 ( http://nmap.org ) at 2015-10-08 11:13 CEST
Nmap scan report for turning.some-name.de (123.45.67.2)
Host is up (0.00033s latency).
Nmap scan report for drucker-sek.some-name.de(123.45.67.19)
Host is up (0.0010s latency).
Nmap scan report for dhcp90-20.some-name.de (123.45.67.22)
Host is up (0.00036s latency).
Nmap scan report for dhcp90-21.some-name.de (123.45.67.27)
```

Then I have go and dial this mannually:

```
ssh user1@123.45.67.2
ssh user1@123.45.67.19
ssh user1@123.45.67.22
ssh user1@123.45.67.27
```

Then finally I know that it's assigned to `123.45.67.22`.

If I can’t give a static IP to the server, **is there a way to automate this crazy net scan + multiple SSH?** (Imagine that I have >100 machines in the net)

---

I could do this to get the IP:

```
$ nmap -sP 123.45.67.0/24 | grep -Eo '[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}'
```

**But how do I write the a for-loop or something to ssh and stop when I successfully ssh-ed into the server?**

---

I get full access to this server but not access to the network admin, it's like plugging in any laptop to the network but in this case the laptop is some sort-of expensive machine. My distro:

```
$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS
Release:    14.04
Codename:   trusty
```

I have also tried to ssh the machine name from another machine within the subnet:

```
$ ssh machine-name.some-name.de
ssh: Could not resolve hostname machine-name.some-name.de: Name or service not known
```

But on the server itself, when I do ssh + tab, I see

```
::1                         
ff02::1                     
ff02::2                     
ip6-allnodes                
ip6-allrouters
ip6-localhost
ip6-loopback
machine-name
machine-name.some-name.de
```

---

Also, I have `avahi-daemon` running already but it seems like the broadcasting is controlled on the network side, only several other machines gets to broadcast their names, e.g. `drucker-sek.some-name.de` and `turning.some-name.de`:

```
$ sudo avahi-daemon
Daemon already running on PID 824
```

Comment: Speak to your network admin. I would expect servers to be configured with fixed IP addresses.

Comment: Lolz, I am the server admin and the network admin takes like tonnes of bureaucracy before i see the guy that can fix the IP for my machine. My users are sort of spamming me with mails everytime, the network admin screws up and cause a power failure or switch/network reset...

Comment: Oh dear. Have you tried bribing the notwork admin with a case of beer or something? ;)

Comment: Because it's just a quite expensive tower that we have bought so that the department users can use to crunch numbers so there's no need to go through the whole IP application and networking process to get the IP fixed to that subnet. It's not exactly providing any services other than users uploading their data to crunch numbers and getting the results. I'm not sure about your multicast comment, could you elaborate? Pardon my noobness ;P

Comment: I have `avahi-daemon` running already but I can't ssh the name =(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about something like:

```
#! /bin/bash
for each in `nmap -sP 123.45.67.0/24 | grep -Eo '[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}' `
do

    echo  $each
    nc -w 2 $each 22

    if [ $? -eq 0 ]
    then
        break;
    fi

done
ssh $each
```

This script will allow 2 seconds to see if SSH answers on the given IP address in turn, and when it gets to the first successful connection it will automatically break out of the loop and attempt to ssh in.

If you are on the same subnet as the PC you are looking for though, there is an easier way to find the IP address - use the ARP table to match the MAC address of your card !

Comment: Actually, why not limit your portscan to find where port 22 is open - nmap -sN 123.45.67.0/24 -p 22